# ReactJS wait until multiple axios get request finish and get results

Tags: reactjs, arrays, axios

I have two API calls I am making simultaneously based on an array of pets; I want to move to the next screen when they finish. The below code is what I currently have; I have to press the button twice for it to go to the next page.

API CALLS:

```
export default class CustomerInformationService {
  getDataFromService = async (petId, type) => {
    if (AppConstants.mockJson === true) {
      return this.getMockData();
    } else {
      console.log("I AM REAL JSON");
      return this.getRealData(petId, type);
    }
  };
  getRealData = async (petId, type) => {
    if (type === "EIP") {
      return this.processEIPRequest(petId);
    } else {
      return this.processTMMRequest(petId);
    }
  };
```

First API Call

```
  processEIPRequest = async (profileId) => {
    const url = AppConstants.endpoint.patterns.getPetProfileInfo.path;
    const params = new URLSearchParams([["ProfileId", profileId]]);
    var response = null;
    AppConstants.axiosEipGET.defaults.headers.common[
      "Authorization"
    ] = `bearer ${token}`;
    await AppConstants.axiosEipGET(url, { params })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("RES", res);
        response = res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response) {
          console.log("ERROR", err.response.data);
          response = err.response;
        }
      });
    return response.data;
  };
```

Second API Call

```
  processTMMRequest = async (profileId) => {
    const url = AppConstants.endpoint.patterns.editPetTMM.path +"/"+ profileId;

    console.log("URL :", url);
    var response = null;
    await AppConstants.axiosGET(url)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("RES", res);
        response = res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response) {
          console.log("ERROR", err.response.data);
          response = err.response;
        }
      });
    return response.data;
  };
}
```

Here is the portion that is calling the code.

```
invokeCustomer([{pets: "pet1", pets: "pet2"}])

 function invokeCustomer(e) {
    console.log("E: ",e)
  

    e["pets"].forEach(pet => {
      const petInitValues = {
        petObj: {
          "name": "",
          "comments": ""
        }
      }
      petInfoDataService.getDataFromService(pet["PETID"], "EIP").then(petData => {
        console.log("PETs: ", petData["PetProfile"])
        petInitValues.petObj.name = petData["PetProfile"].Name
        petDataArray.push(petInitValues)
       setHasPetData(true)
      
  })

  petInfoDataService.getDataFromService(pet["PETID"], "TMM").then(petInfo => {
    console.log("PETs: ", petInfo)
    petInitValues.petObj.comments = petInfo.comments
    petDataArray.push(petInitValues)
    setHasTMMPetData(true)
})
```

I set two `setStates` in the `then` of the response, but I have to press the button twice to go to the navigate portion.

```
  if(hasPetData && hasTMMPetData) {
    console.log("PET ARRAYS: ", petDataArray)
    navigate("/CustomerInformation", { state: { CustomerInformation: e, hasPets: hasPets, petDataArray } });
  }

  })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe call the navigate portion inside `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(hasPetData && hasTMMPetData) {
      console.log("PET ARRAYS: ", petDataArray)
      navigate("/CustomerInformation", { state: { CustomerInformation: e, hasPets: hasPets, petDataArray } });
    }
  }, [hasPetData, hasTMMPetData])
```

This will trigger the navigate portion as soon as both `hasPetData` and `hasTMMPetData` equals true